# Accessing current object's sibling method

Tags: java, class, methods, siblings

I have two (sibling) classes, both is subclass of the same parent. Parent contains all the methods that is shared by the two sibling, and the sibling classes contain only methods that are not shared and has different implementations.

Example,

```
class Parent() {
}
class Sibling1 extends Parent() {
    byte[] sharedSecret;
    int sharedSecretLength;
    public generateKey() {
        sharedSecret = keyAgree.generateSecret());
        sharedSecretLength = sharedSecret.length);
    }
}
class Sibling2 extends Parent() {
    byte[] sharedSecret2;
    int sharedSecretLength2;
    public generateKey() {
        sharedSecret2 = new byte[sharedSecretLength];
        sharedSecretLength2 = keyAgree.generateSecret(sharedSecret2, 0);
    }
    public int getSharedSecretLength() {
        return sharedSecretLength();
    }
}
```

As you can see, both contains same method but implemented differently. My question is, if objects of both class (sibling1 and sibling2) are created AND obj2 generateKey to be generated successfully depends on sharedSecretLength of obj1. Example,

```
Parent obj1 = new Sibling1();
Parent obj2 = new Sibling2();
```

obj1 is instantiated in different class (Server class that I created) and obj2 in different class (Client that I created). If obj1 invoke it's own generateKey --> ((Sibling1)obj1).generateKey(), how can I use use getSharedSecretLength on the same object (obj1) to relay the needed information over to obj2's generateKey to generate successfully? I tried something like (in obj2's generateKey() ):

```
sharedSecret2 = new byte[Sibling1.sharedSecretLength];
```

...and it didn't work. Creating Sibling1 obj1 inside of Sibling2 class and then call it that way, for example,

```
Sibling1 xx = null;
.
.
sharedSecret2 = new byte[((Sibling1)xx).sharedSecretLength];
```

doesn't work because xx is new object. I am trying to use the old obj in which it generated it's key and contains sharedSecretLength that is not 0

If both obj1 and obj2 were created in the same class, it would have been easier.

Please help point me to the right direction

Comment: where is the return type in `generateKey()` method ?

Comment: `Sibling1` and `Sibling2` have **no knowledge** of each other. They don't even know the other exists. Why would an `ArrayList` care that someone created a `HashSet` that also inherits from `AbstractCollection`. Working with that in mind, what exactly are you asking??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
((Sibling1)xx).sharedSecretLength
```

call it like

```
((Sibling1)xx).getSharedSecretLength()
```

In java, you have pass the empty parenthesis if it doesn't accept parameter and it doesnt work by field name, you will have to give the same method name as to what you have defined.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming that `Sibling2` somehow has access to the `Sibling1` instance. Not how to cast and call methods...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should refactor like this so that the generateKey method on Sibling2 has the argument it requires:

```
Sibling1 obj1 = new Sibling1();
obj1.generateKey();
Siblibg2 obj2 = new Sibling2();
obj2.generateKey(obj1.getSharedSecretLength());
```